# Dual Boot - Mounting Windows partition from Linux issues (Windows is hibernated)

Tags: debian, mount, partition, windows

Yes, this type of question has been asked multiple times - however, I have a different scenario since one way works through GNOME, but another doesn't (from the CLI).

Until now, to conveniently mount the Windows partition from my Debian-based Linux distro, I used the GNOME's popular [Disk Usage Analyzer](https://packages.debian.org/sid/gnome/baobab) which lists attached devices and offers automatic mounting through the GUI interface (when an unattached device is clicked as seen in the following picture where the `sudo` password is required).

[image: Disk Usage Analyzer Mounting Process]

This will propely mount `/dev/sda3` to `/media/username/OS` ("OS" is the name of the device). I wanted to try this option from the CLI as well, and to do it safely I monitored spawned processes from the GNOME's tool:

```
> /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd                                                                                                                   
> /sbin/mount.ntfs /dev/sda3 /media/username/OS -o rw,nodev,nosuid,windows_names,uid=1000,gid=1000,uhelper=udisks2                                 
> /usr/lib/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-hotplug-sniffer
```

Nonetheless, if I manually try to enter these in terminal, the following error will show:

```
$ sudo /sbin/mount.ntfs /dev/sda3 /media/username/ -o rw,nodev,nosuid,windows_names,uid=1000,gid=1000,uhelper=udisks2                        

Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.                                                                                                       
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).                                                                                               
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.                                                                                              
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an                                                                            
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation                                                                         
or fast restarting.)                                                                                                                           
Could not mount read-write, trying read-only
```

However, if I try to mount it again using Disk Usage Analyzer, it will work using the same commands - although the Windows is indeed hibernated. I don't get where the problem is in this case?

Additional information: I am not familiar with `systemd-udevd` but when ran concurrently with the `mount` process, it shows this error message: `Failed to unlink /run/udev/queue: No such file or directory`.

Comment: the "problem" is that mount is doing the right thing by preventing you from corrupting the NTFS filesystem.  It's currently in use.  By the Windows system.  Which happens to be hibernating.  If you write to the NTFS partition, then, when windows wakes up, it will be **different to Windows own in-memory knowledge of it**.  This is very likely to cause corruption.

Comment: Use `ntfsfix /dev/sda3` then add `remove_hiberfile`  as option to mount your device.

Comment: @cas So you're implying that Disk Usage Analyzer is doing the wrong thing while not letting us know? I almost never shut down Windows completely, and I have been using this technique for over a year... Thankfully I never had corruption issues, but it something to consider now. Maybe I am lucky that whole this time the process went smoothly?

Comment: lucky, or you didn't write much to sda3 (or write at all - was it mounted RW by Disk Usage Analyser?). or maybe DUA did something like what GAD3R suggested, and the next boot to windows was a full boot rather than a wake from hibernation.

Comment: @cas It indeed mounts it for RW operations (as denoted in the command), and yes, I wrote multiple times - even large files - in the partition. Interesting enough, maybe it's the the latter that you mentioned (although I would maybe notice it from the process monitor script); I didn't pay much attention whether it was a full boot after mounting. Nevertheless, thank you for the heads up both of you